# Extract last value based on "." delimiter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ask:
Extract the last value from a cell that is dot(.) delimited and paste it in another cell.

Sample values in B2:

```
".value1.value2.value3.value4:" -- "value4" to be extracted to C2
".value1:"                      -- "value1" to be extracted to C3
".value1.value2:"               -- "value2" to be extracted to C4
```

NOTE 1: colon(:) exists in every record and a dot(.) is always the first character.

NOTE 2: Not an excel expert

tried the following:

```
=MID(B2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B2,".",CHAR(1),LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,".",""))))+1,LEN(B2)-1)
```

and I get:

"value4:"  -- colon(:) still exists instead of "value4".

appreciate anyone's help to improve the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly not clear from your OP whether you have three strings of values in cells `B2`, `B3` & `B4`, if so then.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(B2:B4,".",-1),":")
```

---

If the above explains wrong then you could do this which may be interpret your way of explaining in the OP

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=CHOOSEROWS(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTSPLIT(B2,,".",1),":",),4,1,2)
```

---

Another alternative, which after editing your OP makes me realize this could be another way:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(B2,".",,1),,-1),":",)
```

---

One another thing stuck to my mind, while looking into your formula, since your using <kbd>CHAR(10)</kbd> is the whole string in cell <kbd>B2</kbd> if so then, one possible way:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(DROP(REDUCE("",B2,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TEXTSPLIT(y,,CHAR(10))))),1),":"),".",-1)
```

---